# Download / Extract / Overwrite .zip file with ZipArchive Class C#

Tags: c#, zip, download, unzip, overwrite

I have been working on an application for my website  for some time now and have finally reached the portion of the development that requires me to download and extract .zip files to a path that is assigned to a variable, however I am not sure how to go about doing this.

For example my program will reference a version file on the users system and read the version, then will check the same version file of the server (www.site.com/client/version.txt for example) and if the users version is lower than the server version it should download a .zip from the server that is named after the current version on the server (1001.zip for example) and extract it to a pre-defined path set in a variable (called "Arma2OAPath" for example) and sileltly overwrite any files that already exist from the .zip file.

Is there any better documentation or examples of how to do something like this other than MSDN?

Any help/resources/examples are much appreciated!

I have been working on this for a while and have been banging my head against the wall on figureing out the easiest way to make the downloader/updater and i believe using .zip files this way is going to be the best method for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you already know how to download a file, once you are done with it you can extract it and check if same file exists on the destination if so delete this file and copy all the files from the zip.

Below is the code to extract and zip files:-

```
private static byte[] Compress(byte[] contentToCompress)
 {
            byte[] compressedBytes;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (GZipStream gs = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    gs.Write(contentToCompress, 0, contentToCompress.Length);
                }

                compressedBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
            return compressedBytes;
}

private static byte[] Decompress(byte[] compressedBytes)
{
            MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream(compressedBytes))
            {
                using (GZipStream gs2 = new GZipStream(ms2, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    byte[] bufffer = new byte[0x400];
                    int count = gs2.Read(bufffer, 0, bufffer.Length);
                    while (count != 0)
                    {
                        outputStream.Write(bufffer, 0, count);
                        count = gs2.Read(bufffer, 0, bufffer.Length);
                    }
                    return outputStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
            return null;
 }
```